# Get IP in PassportJS / ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using PassportJS in an ExpressJS web app.

In app.js:

```
//passportjs google
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: '...',
    clientSecret: '...',
    callbackURL: '...'
  }, user.oauth2Login
));

app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 'email' }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('google', { successReturnToOrRedirect: '/home', failureRedirect: '/login' }))
```

In my user modulue:

```
exports.oauth2Login = function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //get ip here
}
```

How can I get the IP of the user in `oauth2Login`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `passReqToCallback` options.  Details can be found here:

http://passportjs.org/guide/authorize/

(It's a non-obvious location for this documentation, I know.)

Comment: is there anyway to get it also on de/serialize functions? @jared-hanson

Comment: Idan, you could use req.ip when the user logs out!